# Rails loop through 'A..Z' and beyond?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to generate a unique name based on a start_date of a model. I have the following code that's working. However, as you can see, it only supports up to letter Z. Is there a way that I can make it work for beyond Z, like this sequence? `A,B,C,...X,Y,Z,AA,AB,AC,AD,AE...AZ,BA,BB,BC...`

```
  def generate_name
    ("A".."Z").each do |letter|
      random_token = start_date.strftime("%m%d%y") + letter
      break random_token unless Tour.where(name: random_token).exists?
    end
  end
```

Comment: Did you try `('A'..'ZZ')` yet? Or perhaps even `('A'..'ZZZ')`.

Comment: Thanks Sunxperous, it looks like A..ZZZ works well. Much easier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Sunxperous.

This worked:

```
  def generate_name
    ("A".."ZZZ").each do |letter|
      random_token = start_date.strftime("%m%d%y") + letter
      break random_token unless Tour.where(name: random_token).exists?
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def letters
  ('a'..'z').each { |i| yield i }
  letters do |i|
    ('a'..'z').each { |j| yield i+j }
  end
end

def generate_name
  letters do |letter|
    random_token = start_date.strftime("%m%d%y") + letter
    break random_token unless Tour.where(name: random_token).exists?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Sam's answer looks like exactly what you requested but here's another possibly useful way to look at your problem:

Think of your string as a number in base 26, where the digits are represented by 'a'..'z'. The only difference between doing it this way and the way you requested is that the first two-digit number (err, two-letter string) will be *ba* rather than *aa* (assuming that you started counting with *a* = 0, *b* = 1, etc.) and you won't generate any strings starting with *a* (other than the first one) for the same reason you don't write whole numbers starting with 0 (other than the first one).

If it's useful for you to calculate very quickly that the name *dw* was the 100th one you generated, then this approach has merit. It's also a good way to work the word *[hexavigesimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexavigesimal)* into conversations or at least into documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [Kleene star](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star). Not tested, but seems that [RLTK](https://github.com/chriswailes/RLTK) gem can give you such functionality.